# VSCode shell tasks with custom initialization

Tags: shell, visual-studio-code, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I need to define a VSCode `task` that invokes a **shell** command. I would like to be able to control:

- What specific shell it's invoked (e.g .Zsh)
- **How** it is invoked (with what arguments)

### Background / Motivation

My shell task currently takes a few seconds to run. After [much investigation](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/11368) I believe this is because the shell it uses is Zsh, **and** my `.zshrc` uses `git-prompt` from [Oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) in `.zshrc` which can be slow.

This could easily be resolved if the task would invoke the shell using [`zsh --no-rcs`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/547652/invoking-zsh-interactively-asking-it-to-skip-zshrc-or-zshenv/547654#547654), but I can't find any way to tell VSCode to use this command to invoke the shell before it runs the task shell command.